# How to make Eclipse compile patched modules on JDK 9+ by passing the --patch-module javac option to my project compiler? (see pic)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, java-11

Eclipse has to allow that, since javac from JDK allows it without requiring me to contact the CIA for clearance. If eclipse does not allow that, what other Java IDE would allow me. Worst-case scenario I'll just use emacs and terminal.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: That's for running, not for compiling. My problem is at compile time.

Comment: @EddieBravo That's for compiling and running. In _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Module Dependencies_ select the `java.base` module and click the button _Patch with..._. By the way, your screenshot shows the `src/main/java` folder containing the additional subfolder `java.base` which is not correct.

Comment: Eddie: Get to the safe house! The CIA are dispatching the black helicopters as we speak ...

Comment: Thanks @howlger, but I don't think you understood. What I'm trying to do is to recompile `java.lang.StringBuilder`, that's why I need the `java.base` there. Here is how I do without eclipse: `javac --patch-module java.base=src -d patches/java.base src/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.java`

Comment: @EddieBravo [I've already used `--patch-module` successfully](https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/4113#issuecomment-449937230), both in Eclipse and on the command line. If you put your code into `java.base` (which is not required), `java.base` must be the source folder instead of the parent folder (maybe you noticed the file icon with an outline _J_; this is because the Java code is illegally located in a source folder's subfolder with a dot). Please note that `--patch-module` must not be used to add additional methods, fields, classes, etc. or for other API breaking changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Most of the relevant information has already been given in comments, I'm mostly summing it up with a little background and some links*:

Firstly, Eclipse does not accept a folder named `java.base` *within* your source folder. Such layout is used by javac's multi-module mode, but in an IDE like Eclipse that mode is not needed, since we have projects for grouping the modules. In particular Eclipse requires that each project contains at most one module. Now you are free to either (a) define `src/main/java/java.base` as a source folder, or (b) move its content one level up (so that packages start directly in `src/main/java` as in the olden days).

Secondly, for setting up options like `--patch-module` [the UI has been revamped in Eclipse 2019-06](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.12/jdt.php#buildpath-module-dependencies), so I suggest to upgrade Eclipse (if not already done). Then you will find a new tab in the [Java Build Path configuration dialog](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm#module-dependencies) called "Module Dependencies" where you can mark your project as patching `java.base`. (*The method from older versions of Eclipse was: find a node "**Is Modular**" below the library you want to patch and edit (double click) its details. This mode is still supported for a migration period, but it is no longer recommended*).

Thirdly, the Java Build Path, which is used for building/compiling (as the name suggests :) ), should also be respected for launching. To make sure that compile-time and runtime see the same set of options, both dialogs (**Java Build Path** and **Run as ...**) have a button for showing the textual form of the configured options (called JPMS options in the build path configuration).